# How to move towns?

Tags: die2nite

My friends and I all want to play in 1 town so we can work together.

My first friend signed up and joined the same town, but the second joined and he was in a different town. 
I have created a coalition, which seems to be what they are for, but how do I move my 2nrd friend to the town me and my first friend are in?

Also, is there a way to make sure that additional friends join our town?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to join the same town as your friend, you have ensure the following steps to play togher:

1. Make a [coalition](http://www.die2nite.com/free_zombie_game/coalitions) together and make sure you are both part of it.
2. Make sure everyone in the coalition is not in a town already.
3. Set your status to 'ready'
4. Pick a town with at least 5 spaces open (assuming you have a max coalition size of 5)
5. The first time anyone in the coalition clicks on a town to join, they will drag as many coalition members along with them as possible (assuming the town has room).

If you are already in a town, then the only way you can get your friend in is if he has the ability to pick a town to join (only available if they are a hero)